# Audio Jack Safety 230v DC

Tags: dc, connector, voltage-divider, voltage-measurement

I'm using a 3.5mm male to female connection (images below) to a voltage divider network to measure voltage from a solar panel with an Arduino. 230V to roughly 4V.

My question is whether these connections will be unable to handle the voltage and if so, why? They are rated for 1 amp.

[image: Male]

[image: Female]

Comment: What does the datasheet say? No datasheet? No sale! (But they're not suited for your application. The case of the socket is connected to one of the terminals.)

Comment: The connections will be shorted whenever you plug them in/out of the connector. When they are unplugged you will have exposed metal with 230V DC. No, they are not suitable.

Comment: I agree with the safety and short circuit concerns, but would like to know if they will handle 230v DC

Comment: They will not.  Looking at a couple of datasheets from Molex, CUI, etc, all of them say that their 3.5mm TRS connectors are rated for 12VDC.  As for "why not", material selection, insulation clearance, safety standards, etc all could play a part.  If you are looking for a cheap, easy to use, 2- or 3- pin connector that will handle that voltage, I suggest looking at the Micro-Con-X or EN3 series from Switchcraft.

Comment: Also remember to put your HV source on the FEMALE contacts!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should absolutely not be used above ~20-30 volts, and even that's pushing it.

One of the main problems with T(R*)S connectors is that, when inserting or removing the plug, the contacts are briefly shorted together. This isn't much of a problem in audio, but for power applications that means shorting the power supply, and for high voltage sources you can get huge current spikes during the short.

And even if you had a workaround for that, these aren't insulated properly for that kind of voltage. You can just touch bare metal on them, and that's not good when that bare metal could be at 230 V with respect to ground!

More appropriate for this task would be something along the lines of [solar panel connectors](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/photovoltaic-solar-panel-connectors/326), designed for this kind of voltage. Notice how they're large, and insulated all around, so you can't touch bare metal anywhere on them. Some [fully insulated banana plugs](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cal-test-electronics/CT2989-2/6005523) are also suitable for this purpose, but do make sure you know what you're doing when terminating them.

Comment: I agree with the safety and short circuit concerns, but would like to know if they will handle 230v DC. If not, why not.

Comment: Define “handle”. You mean apart from the fact that they are completely inappropriate, insufficiently isolated, they short during insertion and are generally unsafe at high voltages? If in doubt, look it up in the data sheet. If you don’t have a data sheet, don't use them and look for something that has. You’re not going to get any other answer here.

Comment: WIll it melt or burst into flames?

Comment: @Jak Probably not, but it'll certainly break things when you try to use it. Short circuits, arcing, electric shock... I'd say just don't. There are plenty of other connectors out there that are rated for over 240 V, just browse your preferred distributor and use the parametric search for things rated to at least 240 V, preferably at least 300 V to have some margin.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the 4V output from the voltage divider? No problem.

Handle the 240V?  Not a chance. as soon as anything sparks an arc will form and with luck a fuse will be converted to slag before your connector bursts into flame.

Answer (score 0):

No, no, no!

Solar means weather, weather means moisture, moisture means get proper weather-proof gear. Otherwise, be prepared for a lifespan of about 1 hour and not-very-graceful failure.

230v is deadly, 230v DC - doubly so. Get an adequate connector that does not expose signal and connects, when inserted, ground first and signal next. Otherwise, you will get an exposed 230v at half-insert.

And for anything other than headphones, get a connector that does not randomly short on insert.